# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal in this javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

Why am I getting this error???

```
function Overallrating() {
  var amt = this.getField("txt5).value;
    if (amt > 10.5){
      this.getField("Text2").value = "EXCEPTIONAL";
    }else if (amt < 11.00 && amt > 8.5){
      this.getField("Text2").value = "EXCEEDS";
    }else if (amt < 9.00 && amt > 6.5){
      this.getField("Text2").value = "IMPROVEMENT NEEDED";
    }else if (amt < 7.00 && amt > 4.50){
      this.getField("Text2").value = "UNSATISFACTORY";
    }else if (amt < 5.00 && amt > 2.00)
}
```

Comment: double quote not closed `this.getField("txt5").value;`

Comment: Check the second line of your code ```var amt=this.getField("txt5).value; ``` The string is not closed.

Comment: also, once the code is formatted you can see that you are missing the final condition block. always format your code.

Comment: also, there are a couple of obvious errors, but in the future please post the error you are getting with the question.

Answer (score 2):

you wrote

```
var amt=this.getField("txt5).value;
```

you need " at the end of txt5. correct to:

```
var amt=this.getField("txt5").value;
```